# Send Whatsapp message with root

Tags: android, whatsapp, rooted-device, instantmessenger

I'm wondering how some apps manage to send whatsapp messages fully programmatically. I know that it is not possible without root permissions. As I'm not that familiar with programming root enabled android apps, I have no clue how it works. Example apps, that accomplished this are Whatsremote and the SeeBye Scheduler for example. Does anyone of you know how it works?

In particular they send/receive messages without opening whatsapp. So a simple intent that is sent to whatsapp will not work.

Comment: Just as if you were to send out an eMail... using a share intent.

Comment: there is a php api for whatsapp you can use this api for sending whatsapp messages https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

Comment: Sending an intens does not work that way, as it only opens whatsapp but does not allow one to send it directly. To send something through WhatsApi the "app secret" must be known. Maybe we are able to retrieve this secret through the root permission and can then use the api to send the message. I will take a look at retrieving the app secret through the root permissions. Maybe it will work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm pretty sure that apps like SeeBye Scheduler send Whatsapp messages by inserting values directly into one (or more) of the Whatsapp databases (located in /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases directory).

As said, they require root access for doing that.